# Open subset of $GL(n+1,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

I'm trying to show a group is a Lie group, and the easiest path to show that the underlying structure is a differentiable manifold would be to show that the set

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
g & v\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $g\in Gl(V)$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $v\in V$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector, $0$ is a $1\times n$ row vector, and $1$ is an entry, can be identified to an open set of $GL(n+1,\mathbb{R})$, but is this doable? And if so, what is the way to show it?

Comment: I doubt this is an open subset, take a matrix $A$ in there and perturb the bottom right $1$ to be something like $1 - \varepsilon$. For small $\varepsilon$, this resulting matrix can be made very close to $A$ but it won't be of the desired form.

Comment: yeah i had trouble trying to show it, but closed is a lot easier!

Comment: Yup, seems like you got a very clean answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an open set, but a closed subset defined by the equation $x_{n.i}=0,i<n+1, x_{n,n+1}=1$ and a closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie group.

Comment: Hmmm ok, so this is an easier path, thanks!